# Copying values only from one sheet to another -

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to copy from one sheet to another based on criteria. Now I have the code but it does not copy the values. Source sheet only contain formulas and I was trying to copy the values with or wihout formatting.

My Code is:

```
Sub CopyTrue()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hidden Cable Setup")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

j = 2     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("O1:O20000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "True" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign values directly without using `Copy`:

```
Sub CopyTrue()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hidden Cable Setup")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

j = 2     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("O1:O20000").Cells
    If c.Value = "True" Then
       Target.Rows(j).Value = c.EntireRow.Value
       'or just selected columns:
       Target.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
             c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 4).Value
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Is there a way to specify it to copy only few columns, instead of entire row. Say from A:D